# Click on MapMarker and get widget back

Tags: python, kivy, mapview

```
    def addMarker(self,lat:float,lon:float,source:str = "default"):
        if source == "default":
            marker = MapMarker(lat=lat, lon=lon)
        else:
            marker = MapMarker(lat=lat, lon=lon,source = source)
        marker.on_press(print("Test"))
        self.map.order_marker_by_latitude = False
        self.map.add_marker(marker)
```

I want to get the widget itself back when i click on a marker on the map.